Logging a function shows its there but calling it says it doesnt exist - Expo camera SDK
When logging cameraRef.current.pausePreview it shows [function pausePreview] but calling cameraRef.current.pausePreview() gives the error below. However, when calling cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync, which logs [function takePictureAsync], that function calls fine.
Why would takePictureAsync work but pausePreview not, when they are both logging the same thing?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-camera?activeTab=readme
Code:
async function capturePhoto(){
  if (!cameraRef) return;
  console.log("ayeee", cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync, cameraRef.current.pausePreview)
  cameraRef.current.pausePreview();
  let photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
  if (facing === 'front') {
      photo = await manipulateAsync(
          photo.localUri || photo.uri,
          [
              { rotate: 180 },
              { flip: FlipType.Vertical },
          ],
          { compress: 1, format: SaveFormat.PNG }
      );
  }
  setSelectingImage(photo.uri)
  setTakingPhoto(false)
}     

<CameraView 
  ref={cameraRef} 
  flash={flash ? 'on' : 'off'}
  style={{width: scale(330), height: scale(400), overflow: 'hidden' }} 
  facing={facing}
/>

capturePhoto logs:
 LOG  ayeee [Function takePictureAsync] [Function pausePreview]
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
TypeError: this._cameraRef.current?.pausePreview is not a function (it is undefined)

